# the color gradient doesn't work leaflet.JS

Tags: javascript, leaflet, heatmap

Sorry for asking again,
I'm trying to implement a heatmap to Leaflet map but for some reason it seems all data points have the same color and there is no color gradient.

The min value of data is 565 and max is 2455, there's about 900000+ line of data. This is what I get all data shown in red

[image: this is what I get all data shown in red]

```
 var cfg = {

  "radius":2,
  "maxOpacity": .8,

  "scaleRadius": false,
  "useLocalExtrema": true,
  latField: 'lat',
  lngField: 'lng',
  valueField: 'value',
  gradient: { 565:"rgb(255,255,204)",1200:"rgb(255,237,160)",1300:"rgb(254,217,118)",1500:"rgb(254,178,76)",1800:"rgb(253,141,60)",2000:"rgb(252,78,42)",2100:"rgb(227,26,28)",2455:"rgb(177,0,38)" }
};
var heatmapLayer = new HeatmapOverlay(cfg);
var map = new L.Map('map', {
  center: new L.LatLng(28.762929,-9.755429),
  zoom: 5,
  maxZoom: 11,
  minZoom: 5,
  layers: [baseLayer, heatmapLayer]
});
heatmapLayer.setData(testData);

layer = heatmapLayer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use numbers between 0 and 1 for the gardient.

```
gradient: {
    // enter n keys between 0 and 1 here
    // for gradient color customization
    '.5': 'blue',
    '.8': 'red',
    '.95': 'white'
  },
```

https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-full-customization.html

https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/docs.html

Comment: thanks it worked but data still have the same color like it give the same color as the given to key 1